# Magento SOAP Shipment

Tags: soap

I want to get tracking details for an order:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/sales/salesOrderShipment/sales_order_shipment.info.html

If I have an order object, how do I get the shipmentIncrementId? How do I query shipments, based on an order_id or a increment_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can load order by its increment id as below

**$orderIncrementId = 100000055'';**

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId);

$shipment = $order->getShipmentsCollection()->getFirstItem();

$shipmentIncrementId = $shipment->getIncrementId();
```

hope this will work for you.

Comment: Hi, will it work it work this this model: http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/sales_order.info.html

Comment: yes just grab `Increment ID` from response and load as above code.